# Is the volume of the largest hyperrectangle inscribed in a convex polytope always larger than some fixed proportion of the polytopes volume?

Tags: combinatorics, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, volume, convex-geometry

Fix a positive integer $n$. For any convex polytope $\mathcal{P}$ of dimension $n$, let $V_\mathcal{P}$ denote its volume and let $K_{\mathcal{P}}$ denote the maximum possible volume of an $n$-dimensional hyperrectangle completely contained in $\mathcal{P}$.

What is the minimum possible value of the ratio $$\frac {K_{\mathcal{P}}}{V_{\mathcal{P}}}$$ taken over all bounded convex polytopes $\mathcal{P}$ of dimension $n$?

If we cannot compute the minimum value of the ratio exactly, can we prove some lower bounds for this quantity?

**Note:** The application I am interested involves a much more constrained version of the above problem. This alternate version is written below, and any progress on that question is greatly appreciated as well.

**Alternate Problem**

The problem is the same as above, except we consider $\mathcal{P}$ living in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the faces of $\mathcal{P}$ are all of the form $x_i = c_i$ or of the form $x_j - x_i = c_{ij}$, where the $c_i$ and $c_{ij}$s are constants. In other words, the faces are either perpendicular to the axes, or are very speciffic faces that cut two of the faces at $45^{\circ}$.

Moreover, $K_{\mathcal{P}}'$ is taken to be the maximum possible value volume of a hyperrectangle *with sides parallel to the axes in $\mathbb{R}^n$* that is contained in $\mathcal{P}$.

In this modified scenario, we still want to compute lower bounds on $$\min \frac {K_{\mathcal{P}}'}{V_{\mathcal{P}}}$$ where the minimum is now taken taken over all bounded convex polytopes $\mathcal{P}$ of dimension $n$, with the constraints on types of faces?